# react suspense, why is a waterfall occurring in a network request?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm studying grammar about suspense while listening to and watching a lot of information.

When I wrote the code below, I saw an example that there was no network waterfall.
However, when I tried to execute the code, the network delay continues to occur.
Is there anything I'm missing?

index.tsx

```
import { useRef, useState, Suspense } from "react";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";
import Contact from "./Contact";

export default function Home() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(1);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  const selectTab = () => {
    setCount(query);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => setQuery(Number(e.target.value))}
        value={query}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={selectTab}>
        post (slow)
      </button>
      <Suspense fallback={<h1> Loading...</h1>}>
        <TodoList userId={count} />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
```

TodoList.tsx

```
import {
  memo,
  forwardRef,
  useImperativeHandle,
  useRef,
  useEffect,
  useLayoutEffect,
  useState,
  useReducer,
  Suspense,
} from "react";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const TodoList = ({ children, userId }: any, ref: React.Ref<any>) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  async function fetchUser(userId: number, delay = 0) {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userId}`
    );
    const user = response.data;
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay)); // 임의 딜레이
    return user;
  }

  const { data: user, isLoading } = useQuery(
    [userId],
    () => fetchUser(userId),
    {
      suspense: true,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      retry: false,
    }
  );

  if (!user) {
    return <h1>empty user data</h1>;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{user.name} 님이 작성한 글</p>
      {children}
      <Suspense fallback={<h4>글 목록 가져오는중...</h4>}>
        <Contact userId={userId} />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Contact.tsx

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";

function Contact({ userId }: any) {
  async function fetchPost(userId: number, delay = 0) {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${userId}`
    );
    const post = await response.data;
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay)); // 임의 딜레이
    return post;
  }

  const { data: posts, isLoading } = useQuery(
    ["post", userId],
    () => fetchPost(userId),
    {
      suspense: true,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      retry: false,
    }
  );

  if (!posts) {
    return <span>empty posts data</span>;
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post: any) => (
        <li key={post.id}>
          {post.id}. {post.title}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default Contact;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only rendering the `Contact` component *after* the `TodoList` has successfully fetched data. Fetching cannot be parallelised if you do conditional rendering like that.